# Regular expression to validate the given input which accepts one space or Hyphen which is part of the text length and start with 97

Tags: regex

to validate the text using the regex which allows one space or hyphen start with 97.

```
regex: ^97(?=[0-9]+[ -]?[0-9]+)(?!([0-9])(?:\1|[ -]){2}).{3}$ 

ex: 97123 valid
    97-12 valid but not working as per the above reg 
    971-2 valid  
    9712- not valid
```

Comment: Might help to change quantifiers in first part to [`^97(?=[0-9]*[ -]?[0-9]+$)`...](https://regex101.com/r/9PzH3p/1) (also added `$` end anchor) further I have not studied your pattern.

Comment: A bit shorter version: [`^97(?=.{3})(?!(\d)\1\1)\d*[- ]?\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/nnwcX3/1) I wondered however if you meant to match eg `97-11` (only `1` after `97`)

Comment: @bobblebubble: I think you will still need `$` anchor like `(?=.{3}$)`

Comment: Good catch @anubhava! Thank you, yes of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^(?=[0-9]+(?:[ -][0-9]+)?$)(?!([0-9])(?:\1|[ -]){2})97.{3}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VtW9m6/1)

The first lookahead, `(?=[0-9]+(?:[ -][0-9]+)?$)`, now requires

- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[ -][0-9]+)?` - an optional occurrence of a space or hyphen and then one or more digits
- `$` - end of string

to be present immediately to the right of the current location (that is the start of string).

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements can be covered with this simplified regex:

```bash
^97(?=.{3}$)(?:[ -]?\d)+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9OWpCZ/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `97`: Match `97`
- `(?=.{3}$)`: Match 3 more character till end
- `(?:[ -]?\d)+`: Match an optional hyphen or space followed by a digit. Match this non-capturing group 1+ times
- `$`: End